# Beergun too much O² in bottles?

Tags: beer, beer-tools

I've bought a beergun to fill my Beer from the fermentor into my bottles. I got the Feeling that it shoots alot of O² in my Beer. The Beer turned Out super hazy (Not Sure If its because of the gun).

Are beerguns bad in generell or do i miss Something?

I rack from one fermentor to another to leave trub behind and than just fill up the bottles from the dischard.

For my next batch i'll do 50% of the bottles with the beergun and 50% without and See if the gun is the Problem.

Comment: How do you do this exactly? In particular, do you filter your beer after fermentation, or rack to secondary, to leave trub behind? What does the end of the hose that attaches to the beer gun look like? Will it suck up the trub from the bottom of the fermentor? If so, look into some barrier like a racking cane filter or a cap that many racking canes have. How long do you let the beer sit after bottling? Does the haze settle? Does it change with temperature? Do you have the same issue when you don't use the beer gun? (When you answer these, please [edit] the question; don't add comments.)

Comment: Was just curious If someone else had bad expirements with beer gun and oxygen. I'll make a Test on the next batch to See if the gun is the actuall Problem or If Something went wrong in mashing

Answer (score 1):

BeerGuns are for bottling finished beer from a pressurised keg.

They're not well suited for fermenter to bottle transfers for conditioning.